# Perform n mongodb updates at a time using SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core

I have a queue of jobs, and I want to process 20 at a time using asynchronous concurrency.

When processing a job, some updates in MongoDb are made an a file gets uploaded to a server, that's up to 1GB and would take about 40 seconds.

What do you think?

**Program.cs**

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync(args).Wait();
}

 public static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection
            .AddLogging()
            .AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program))
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        await serviceProvider.GetService<App>().Run(20);
    }
```

**App.cs**

```
public class App
{
    private readonly IQueueService _queueService;
    private readonly IUploadService _uploadService;
    private SemaphoreSlim _throttle;

    public App(IQueueService queueService, IUploadService uploadService)
    {
        _queueService = queueService;
        _uploadService = uploadService;
    }

    public async Task Run(int initialCount = 3)
    {
        _throttle = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount);

        var jobs = await _queueService.GetQueue();

        var tasks = jobs.Select(ProcessJob);
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine("Upload finished...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async Task ProcessJob(JobDto JobDto)
    {
        await _throttle.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            // Process file
            Guid.TryParse(JobDto.JobName, out var jobId);
            var isUploaded = await _uploadService.Upload(JobDto.CreatedBy, jobId);

            // Update collection
            await _queueService.DeleteJobQueue(JobDto.Id);
        }
        finally
        {
            _throttle.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `The current problem that I can see, if a job takes to long, and blocks the task, it will miss new jobs, and the queue will get crowded...` That suggests your code does not work as intended. StackOverflow is a right place for the question, IMO.

Comment: It's also not very clear what _exactly_ you're trying to achieve, since this is not a service. IDK, what populates the queue, how the worker (App) knows it needs to pick more jobs to make them active tasks, etc.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko I'm aware of what questions are for SO, other than that I'm interested of a code review.

Comment: The code is clearly not doing what it is supposed to do. CodeReview only focuses on _working_ code. I quote: `How to Ask.
Improve code that you wrote or maintain, through peer review.
Your question must contain code that is already working correctly, and the relevant code sections must be embedded in the question. Please avoid stripping out key details that may be relevant to the review. If your code is incomplete or not working, you should ask for help on another site.`

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko What does it mean,"code incomplete" should i post all my repository? What are key details? Every irelevant detail? I'm just interested a review for asynchronus concurency, and only what I've posted, and I don't agree with your opinion, but i respect it.

Comment: `The current problem that I can see, if a job takes to long, and blocks the task, it will miss new jobs` -- I read it as, "the code does not do what it is expected to do".

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko but I didn't  asked for a solution, did I? I understand what code review is about. At the current moment I'm working to improve this. It wasn't a must, just nice to have. I just want a code review for Semaphore. I remove that phrase, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @SGN does this code run 20 jobs at the same time. I tried implementing it but doesn't look like its running parallel.

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues with the provided code:

1. You are using a queue, however I only see a single call to retrieve items from the queue, when you start the application. Does this mean all the jobs are there when `Run()` is called?
2. You want to process `20` jobs at a time, but can `_uploadService.Upload` actually handle unlimited simultaneous requests? Or does it silently peak at something like `2 * number of cores` or the size of the thread pool?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. It doesn't silently peak. I pass the number of workers as parameters when I run the console app.